# PHP Windows 7 IPv6 Work-Around ip column can not be null

Tags: php, ipv6

With the following PHP/SQL...

```
function ip2long6($ip)
{//ipv6 to ipv4 (string) to get Windows 7 local working
// Temp work-around until we convert the string to support ipv6 natively in SQL.
 if (substr_count($ip, '::')) {$ip = str_replace('::', str_repeat(':0000', 8 - substr_count($ip,':')).':',$ip);}

 $ip = explode(':',$ip);
 $r_ip = '';

 foreach ($ip as $v) {$r_ip .= str_pad(base_convert($v,16,2),16,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);}

 return base_convert($r_ip,2,10);
}

$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string(ip2long6($ip));
INSERT INTO log (ip) VALUES (INET_ATON('1208321'))
```

I get the following error...

> Column 'ip' cannot be null

How can we get $ip to be IPv4 compatible for now?

---

A working answer...

```
if (is_int($ip)) {$ipsql = mysql_real_escape_string("INET_ATON('$ip')");}
else {$ipsql = mysql_real_escape_string($ip);}
```

With this I simply reply `INET_ATON('$ip')` with `$ipsql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting a stringed-int using INET_ATON. that function expects a dotted.quad address, e.g.

```
INET_ATON('127.0.0.1');
```

is not a valid input, so the function returns null:

```
mysql> select inet_aton('12345'), inet_aton('127.0.0.1');
+--------------------+------------------------+
| inet_aton('12345') | inet_aton('127.0.0.1') |
+--------------------+------------------------+
|               NULL |             2130706433 |
+--------------------+------------------------+
```